# How to execute Javascript after Rails' remote form `disable_with` functionality has completed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using `disable_with`, and cannot get the button text change to persist (because it is being overwritten by the `disable_with` functionality). As soon as I remove `, data: { disable_with: '...'` the buttons are updated as expected.

Is there a way to perform actions after the `disable_with` functionality has completed?

**form:**

```
<%= form_for @user, html: {id: 'follow-form'}, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= button_tag id: 'follow-btn', data: { disable_with: '...' } do %>
        Follow
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**js:**

```
$('#follow-form').on('ajax:success',function(data, status, xhr){
    if (status.action == 'follow') {
        $('#follow-btn').text('Unfollow');
    } else {
        $('#follow-btn').text('Follow');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe without `disable_with` and:

```
$('#follow-form').on('ajax:send',function(data, status, xhr){
    $('#follow-btn').text('Please wait...').attr({disabled: true});
});
```

And when AJAX request succeeds:

```
$('#follow-form').on('ajax:success',function(data, status, xhr){
    if (status.action == 'follow') {
        $('#follow-btn').text('Unfollow').attr({disabled: false});
    } else {
        $('#follow-btn').text('Follow').attr({disabled: false});
    }
});
```